# In what scenarios should we use a pallet to call an ink! smart contract?

Tags: ink, pallet

For example,

- pallet

They use pallet-dapps-staking to call ink! smart contract

https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/tree/master/pallets/dapps-staking

- Runtime

https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/runtime/shibuya/src/lib.rs#L688

Comment: Please clarify your question. The title is clear but it is a very broad question and with the information you are providing it is not clear what you are questioning about

Comment: Here's an in depth usecase: https://medium.com/@GenesisDAO/introducing-the-hookpoints-pallet-377de6680c2d

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7c_GAZuEd8&t
We can also refer this valuable workshop from Sub0 2023

Answer (score 2):

First, in any case you need a pallet to call a smart contract (SC). `Pallet-contracts` and `pallet-evm` provide the functionality to call a WASM SC or Solidity SC respectively.

There can be many reasons to have other pallets in your runtime interact with SCs or the other way around. This post on the Polkadot Forum can maybe help you get a grasp of it: https://forum.polkadot.network/t/urban-planning-in-the-paraverse-with-ink/2617